# Expresso Store - Stripe Payment Issue

Tags: expresso-store, stripe

I have a template that submits to stripe and gets back a 200 and a token through store.

But when the token comes back, I am getting no 'complete the order process' at all. The template doesn't submit and no error shows. I get no order in Store control panel, and no purchase call for stripe.

Can you shed some light on this?

https://gist.github.com/emagine/7248059

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console? What happens after the Stripe token is returned? Is the page submitted at all?

Comment: no javascript errors there at all. The stripe token is returned and the form does nothing from that point onward. nothing is submitted.

Comment: just the console logs there you'll see that the info is correct in coming back, it just doesn't trigger anything in store itself

[Log] stripe (checkout3, line 346)
[Log] 200 (checkout3, line 364)
[Log] tok_102r2H2kj2TUqVRwoW7rukOg (checkout3, line 365)

Comment: register_member="yes"  If I take this out of the checkout tag, it allows me to purchase as a logged-in member. If I am not logged in, how am I meant to purchase? This specifically was holding back the payment form.

Comment: If there were errors then the form was definitely submitting. You generally need to check the network tab to see what is getting posted to the server.

Comment: There's weren't any errors, it had to do with the register member='true' in the parameters. If I took that out, it happens, but there was no feedback in the inline errors part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a form that is not submitting you should always remove `error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'` from your template to see if you have any errors being reported that are not templated.

Having said that if you are trying to register a member during the checkout process you need to include both a `password` and `confirm_password` field in your template at this point.

Comment: What do you do if you have both scenarios? one logged in and one not? Submit two different forms? one without register_member, and one not?

Comment: You can use `{field:register_member}` instead in your checkout template along with some JavaScript to show/hide the password fields when a user ticks a checkbox.